# Table Layout break outside the page in pdf merging using mpdf

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf library to merge pdf files, I found that if a page has table then the table break outside the page, I searched on MPDF documentation but I couldn't find solution, while other pages are normal if there is no table on that page. I am looking forward to help me out to solve this problem

[image: here is screenshot]

Comment: Have u tried by using style="page-break-inside: avoid;" this  css style for table?

Comment: where i have to define this css style i am just taking muliple pdf files and merging them in new file.